# Can I test a javascript file inside my public folder with jasminerice and rails 3.2.8?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, tdd, jasmine

I am having a little bit of trouble testing a javascript file inside my rails application. I have this file inside my public directory because I want to serve it statically.

I am currently using **jasminerice 0.0.9** to test all my other javascript files which are inside app/assets and those are seem to be working right.

When trying to test my public javascript file I am not being able to require it inside my test by doing:

```
#= require /public/myfile.js
```

Do anyone knows if it is possible to test my file inside my public directory with jasminerice or if there is any other way to test it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a:

```
//= require_tree public
```

.. before the file inclusion. It is also just (no extension):

```
#= require myfile
```